# React import image from local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

How can i import local storage image in react?

My data looks like this;

```
{ image:"newimage.jpeg" }
```

and I tried to do this:

```
<img src={require("../../assets/images/`${data.image}`")}>
```

But its not working. Any suggestion will be glad.

Comment: There's no need for `require`; just use `src={\`../../assets/images/${data.image}\`}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to have only the backticks `` around the file path:

```
<img src={require(`../../assets/images/${data.image}`)}>
```

And `require` is Node-specific IIRC - you may need to use `import` for a React project (unless it's both React and Node somehow).

Answer (score 1):

Simply importing your image as a module should do the trick.

From create-react-app docs (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Yes i know this way but main problem is my image path comes from my data

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I think that Jack Bashford's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load local images, it should be in the public folder.
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#when-to-use-the-public-folder

You can also import the image you want to use. 
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files